# How to implement date time picker in WPF?

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to implement date time picker in my C# WPF application, but I couldn't find any controls as such. How can I implement it?

Answer (score -1):

Use the [WPF Toolkit Extended](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/), it contains a prebuilt DateTimePicker that supports MVVM and Databinding.